# Accessing ViewController's variables from UIActionSheet delegate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates, scope

I have the following code:

```
@implementation SendMapViewController

NSMutableArray *emails;
```

At this method I create emails array and I add some NSStrings:

```
- (BOOL) peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker
       shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson: (ABRecordRef)person {

    ABMultiValueRef emailInfo = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

    NSUInteger emailCount = ABMultiValueGetCount(emailInfo);

    if (emailCount > 1) {

        UIActionSheet *emailsAlert = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                      initWithTitle:@"Select an email"
                                      delegate:self 
                                      cancelButtonTitle:nil
                                      destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];

        emails = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: emailCount];

        for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < emailCount; i++) {
            NSString *emailFromContact = (NSString *)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(emailInfo, i);

            [emails addObject: emailFromContact];

            [emailsAlert addButtonWithTitle:emailFromContact];

            [emailFromContact release];
        }

        [emailsAlert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];

        [emailsAlert showInView:self.view];

        [emailsAlert release];
    }
    else {
        ...
    }

    CFRelease(emailInfo);

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    return NO;
}
```

As you can see in code, if there are more than one email I show and UIActionSheet. When user clicks on a button representing and email, I want to execute the following code:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if ([emails count] >= buttonIndex) {
        NSString *contactEmail = (NSString *)[emails objectAtIndex:buttonIndex];

        ...
    }
}
```

But emails array hasn't got any email. What I'm doing wrong?

I'm developing for iPhone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `emails` object was probably autoreleased when you weren't looking. Replace the line:

```
emails = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: emailCount];
```

with:

```
[emails release];
emails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:emailCount];
```

so that `emails` is not autoreleased. (**Remember**, you own anything returned by `init`, but objects returned by convenience constructors like `arrayWithCapacity:` come autoreleased.)

The **best** solution is to declare a property:

```
@property (retain) NSMutableArray* emails;
```

and then use:

```
[self setEmails:[NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: emailCount]];
```

This second method, using a property, is really the best, because it is more flexible and clear. This way, the property's accessors (which you create with `@synthesize`) will handle calling `retain` for you.

Comment: I thought it was something related to emails variable that it was declared in another thread of execution (as with. NET if you want to update the interface from another thread of execution that is not the one that has created).